# Cucumber reports isnt coming properly, print statements aren't expandable in cucumber report generated by Karate

Tags: cucumber, karate

Cucumber reports isnt coming properly, print statements aren't expandable in cucumber report generated by Karate

You can see in attached screenshot the print statements isnt accessible/expandible to view any variable data.

[image]

Tried enableLogs config but dint work.

Comment: this is NOT the karate report, it is some other 3rd party report, perhaps cucumber related